# Copy static files to volume on deployment?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

How can I ensure that the most recent static files created during deployment of 
a Django application are copied to a volume? My `web` container defines a Django application that, when built, runs `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear`.  This moves all static files into the `/usr/src/app/static_files` directory. I'd like these static files to become available in the `staticdata` volume such that nginx can serve them. In other words, the contents of `/usr/src/app/static_files` should overwrite the contents of existing files in the `staticdata` volume. Otherwise nginx will keep serving older copies of files such css files and images, instead of the updated files collected by Django.

Is this possible? It feels like I am using volumes wrong for this purpose, since their purpose is persisting data.

**Edit1:** Is there perhaps a way to create a "temporary volume" when the application is deployed, which is destroyed when the application is undeployed? If so, how do I do this, and how do I make this volume also available to nginx?

**Edit2:** If I am not mistaken an option would be to use a bind mount, but I've read that these should be avoided if possible such that an application is not dependent on the structure of the host's filesystem.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    env_file:
    - web-variables.env
    expose:
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - staticdata:/usr/src/app/static_files
      - staticdata:/usr/src/app/uploaded_files
    command: "./django-entrypoint.sh"
    depends_on:
      - database

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - staticdata:/data/www
    depends_on:
      - web

  database:
    image: postgres:9.2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  staticdata:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible - you were nearly there. By passing the option `--clear` to `collectstatic`, it will clear the directory before collecting the static files. That's not the behaviour you want. Simply run it without that flag:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

And it should only copy over newer static files which don't exist at the destination yet.

Looking forward, you might want to consider having separate containers for static files and media files (user-generated content) as things could get confusing otherwise as seen here :)

Comment: I followed your advice and separated the containers. However, unless I did something wrong, when making an update to a static file (e.g. `style.css`) and redeploying the app, the newer copy does not overwrite the already existing file in the volume. These are infect the opposite semantics of what it should be for the Django static files: The files in the volume should be completely discarded in favour of the new files collected by Django.

Comment: This would definitely add new static files into the volume but if there's an update inside one of the existing files then it won't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default location `docker nginx` image is looking at is `/usr/share/nginx/html` and not `/data/www` as you wanted it.

So just change this line and it should work:

```
 nginx:
    ...
      - staticdata:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ...
```

Comment: My apologies if my question was not clear. My static files are being served correctly (i.e. directories are correctly configured), but the static files collected by Django at every deployment need to overwrite the files already in the `staticdata` volume. Otherwise old css, images, etc. are served to the user instead of the updated files in the Django application.

Comment: okay, sorry for misunderstood. I don't think there is anything wrong with the command or the `docker-compose.yml`. If it doesn't copy it could be your Django setting. So you can try run it with input first to see if it is copied correctly like this `docker-compose run --rm web ./manage.py collectstatic`. If it's also not working then likely the `STATIC_ROOT` of your Django setting is wrong

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the data from `/usr/src/app/static_files` is only copied to pre-populate the volume with data (i.e. when it is created) from the container. Otherwise no data is written. This makes sense, as I am certain that Django is correctly collecting the static files in `/usr/src/app/static_files`, while the volume still contains the old files. Unfortunately I cannot find the part of the documentation where it explicitly states the behaviour, but [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes) it only says "A new volume’s contents can be pre-populated by a container."